# ECS-CLI Compose Can't Find Entrypoint File

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I'm running into an issue while trying to deploy a Django app to ECS via `ecs-cli compose`.  When I run `docker-compose up` locally it works well, but when I use `ecs-cli compose up` it can't find my entrypoint file.  I've SSH'd into the EC2 instance and using `docker run -it {image_id} sh` verified that the file exists at the expected path and is executable.  Here is my Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.7-slim-stretch
MAINTAINER mail@test.com

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    libpq-dev

# install dependencies
COPY requirements/base.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
# entrypoint.sh is in the current directory and gets copied over here
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I run the `ecs-cli compose up` command it tries to start the containers but ultimately they end up 'STOPPED'.  When I run `ecs-cli ps` it displays the error:
`STOPPED Reason: CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh\": stat /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh: no such file or directory": unknown`

Other people on SO have run into similar issues when using single quotes around the ENTRYPOINT path (I'm using double quotes) or when the entrypoint.sh file is declared as bash instead of sh (mine is declared as sh) or when Windows line endings might be present (I'm on MacOS).

I'm new to Docker and ECS so thank you in advance for any help or insight!

Comment: Just after your `COPY . /usr/src/app/` statement, try running `RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh` or `ls -al /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh`. If there is any problem the docker build should only fail.

Comment: @Rayclank I tried both of these and still get the same error. The local build completes successfully, I push the image to ECR, run ecs-cli compose up and it fails with the same error.